# Find the minimum index in an array such that some key is less than or equal to Array[index]

Tags: binary-search

I'm trying to change binary search a bit so instead of just finding the index of an element if and only if it is in the array, I want to find the minimum index such that Array[index] >= key. So if I have an array like `int A[5] = {1,5,10,15,20}` and I called `search(A, 12, 5)` (where 5 is just the length of the array) it would return `=> 3` since `A[3] = 15 >= 12`. If I searched for something above 20 it would just give me `5` back or some other arbitrary number.

I'm trying to write it as closely as conventional binary search as possible. Any help?

(here's conventional binary search)

```
int binarysearch(int A[], int key, int length) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = length - 1;
    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (key < A[mid]) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else if (key > A[mid]) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to add a check when the key is less than the mid entry which would look at the previous entry. If the key is greater than that entry, we have our answer (because if you stepped one down the list, the entry wouldn't be greater than the key). So, the code would look something like this:

```
int low = 0;
int high = length - 1;
while (low <= high)
{
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if (key < A[mid])
    {
        high = mid - 1;
        if (high < 0 || key > A[high])
        {
            return mid
        }    
    }
    else if (key > A[mid])
    {
        low = mid + 1;
    }
    else
    {
    return mid;
    }
}
return -1;
```

It would need to be more complicated if your list allowed repeats, but it should work otherwise.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306119/868941

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `return -1`, just return `mid`